# npm init react-app ./firstapp creates only json file, not react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am on Windows and using the Ubuntu shell to create a React app as follows

`npm init react-app ./firstapp`

But this only creates a package.json file after a few prompts and not a folder with the react app

when I do `npm --version`, I get the following
3.5.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this code

**npx create-react-app**

or

follow this link

https://create-react-app.dev/